# Program to generate a LaTeX table from an image containing a table

Tags: ocr, latex

I'm looking for a program that can:

- generate a LaTeX table from a scanned page containing a table

E.g. if the input is

[image]

the ouput would be the corresponding LaTeX code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
  \hline
  7C0 & hexadecimal \\
  3700 & octal \\ \cline{2-2}
  11111000000 & binary \\
  \hline \hline
  1984 & decimal \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

And if possible:

- free
- works on Windows 7
- takes different image format as well as PDF as input

Comment: It's a feature request for Tabula: https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula/issues/409

Comment: @bariumbitmap great!